# how to use "$(document).ready(function) when open new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".main").onepage_scroll({
        sectionContainer: "section",
        responsiveFallback: 600,
        loop: true
    });
});
```

when click on run button call "nwin" function, in that function i can open new window using open(), that time i am using this function but this is not load fuction new window is open.

here button code,

```
<div class="resultContainer">
    <div style="height:400px;">
        <div style="float:left; width:100%;  height: 93px; margin: 20px 0 0 60px;"> <span class="containerTitle" style="    top: 65px;">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="button_example"  id="result" style="color: white;">Result</a></span>

        </div>
    </div>
```

and when click on this call function is

```
$("a#result").click(nWin);

var htmlEditor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("html"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: "text/html",
    matchBrackets: true
});

function nWin() {
    htmlEditor.save();
    var w = window.open();
    $(w.document.head).load(function () {
        $(".main").onepage_scroll({
            sectionContainer: "section",
            responsiveFallback: 600,
            loop: true
        });
    });

    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "jquery.onepage-scroll.js";
    $(w.document.head).append(script);
    $(w.document.head).append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="onepage-scroll.css" type="text/css" />');
    $(w.document.head).append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo_data.css" type="text/css" />');
    $(w.document.head).append("<style>" + $('#css').val() + "</style>" + $('#js').val());
    $(w.document.body).html($('#html').val());
}
```

Comment: Try to put your code after the line `script.src = "jquery.onepage-scroll.js";`

Comment: Why do you need to use `document.ready`, rather than appending your `onepage_scroll` script after the content?